# Measuring UI performance in React Native Mobile App

Tags: react-native, performance

We have developed a mobile app using reactive native for one of my client. The screens are taking long time to load. When analyzed, we found that the delay is in the API side. However, the client expects a report to prove that the delay is not from the UI side.

Is there a way/tool to measure how much time does the APP takes to render each screen from the API response?

Regards,
Anbu Varadhan

Comment: You can use Flipper tool for debugging API. Here you can find https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/plugins/network/

Comment: Hey, if you are sure the delay is from API, then use any other tool (for ex: curl) to fetch the API and let the customer see how long it takes.